# Linux device driver: stream data into a single register

Tags: linux, embedded, driver

I'm trying to stream a piece of data as fast possible into a single register in hardware and would appreciate some advice. That is, write every word of the data into the register in sequence.

I imagine streaming the data in by redirecting into the device file:
data.bin > /dev/stream_df0

I know this is vague, but it's the first time I'm doing something like this and will appreciate anything you have to throw at me:

? What type of considerations should I take before I start on this project to make this as fast as possible?

? Would a character device driver handle streaming well/be suitable for this task?

? Is the way I'm going about this entirely inefficient/inpractical?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A character device driver would seem appropriate, yes :)  The actual mechanics of the lowest-level interrupt/DMA that does the actual stuffing into the hardware FIFO-thingy are device/architecture specific.  If this is the first time you have implemented such a driver, I wish you the very best of luck:)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to do something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) { outp(data[i],port_number); }
```

I would try to do this using the "rep outsb/outsw/outsd" assembler instructions.

Comment: Oh - it's not likely to be THAT easy ;(